# PHPMailer hangs on sending bulkmails

Tags: php, email, centos, phpmailer, html-email

I had successfully set up a web app using PHP, PHPmailer on centos server for sending bulk emails to customers. customer emails get from SQL database. It successfully works and it sends one email and sleeps 20 seconds, then do this process as a loop. The database has 6000 email addresses. In this process, the server hangs by sending about 100 emails. So I have to run this program again.
Why does this hang?
I don't get a PHP error or a PHP timeout.

This is my code:`

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "test");
mysql_select_db("user", $con);
$query = "select email from client_detail";
$result = mysql_query($query, $con);
$email = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $email[] = $row['email'];
}
foreach ($email as $to) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->setFrom('bestweb@nic.lk');
    $mail->addAddress($to);
    $mail->Subject = 'Bestweb2018';
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Body = '<html>
                        <head>
                            <title>BestWeb.lk 2018</title>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                            <table style="width: 760px;" >
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <img src="cid:banner" alt="bestweb.lk 2018" width="760px" height="167px" /> 
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                              </body>
                    </html>
            ';
    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('images/bannergold.gif', 'banner');

    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message was not sent ' . $to;
        echo "<br>";
        echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent ' . $to;
        echo "<br>";
    }

    sleep(20);
}
?>
```

Comment: what happens then? no errors in the logs?

Comment: sleep(20) is too high, less than 5 is enough. like 2 or 3.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to sleep at all.  Wouldn't you rather open up an STMP connection, leave it open, and send them as fast as you can?

Comment: there are no errors in the error logs

Comment: The mail server sends too many emails for company works. That's why I put sleep time for 20 seconds. I'll try sleep time less than 5 seconds

Comment: This code is very inefficient, and because you're creating a new instance every time around the loop, you can't use keepalive. Base your code on [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).

Comment: First I run this program on ssh. then hanged. After I run this program on the server directly through the terminal.  Then it is not hung anymore. Thanks all for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server can be overloaded because of 20 seconds sleep `sleep(20)` for each iteration.

> Reduce sleep time to few seconds like 2 or 3.

```
sleep(3)
```

> Enable display errors, add this top of the script

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

> Log email completion status on log file because you are running a loop all echo data goes to buffer so nothing would get print until loop gets finished.

```
if (!$mail->send()) {
    @file_put_contents('email-logs.txt', 'Message was not sent ' . $to ." - error :" . var_export( $mail->ErrorInfo, true) . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
} else {
    @file_put_contents('email-logs.txt', 'Message has been sent ' . $to . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: After run on the server directly through the terminal, the problem solved. thanks

Comment: Glad to know that you sorted it out. Happy coding